# How to create a slider screen (As in Tweetdeck) in Android?

Tags: android, screen

We want to create a screen which should have different list views and the user can slide (Left or right) to view another list view (just like in TweetDeck and in home screen on some Android OS version). There is also a list of dots which identify how many list views are there.

Please refer to the screen shot.
[image]

Thanks in advance,
Afzal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it:
http://code.google.com/p/deezapps-widgets/

Works like a charm.

Thank you.

Comment: But how to launch activities, this when sliding shows a layout not an activity. Any idea please?

Answer (score 5):

In fact this control called ViewPager, now is supported by Android. You can check a compatibility package name android-support-v4.jar.

Some nice ViewPager samples with indicator is:

- android-viewflow: https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow
- Android-ViewPagerIndicator: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

P/s: Checkout my app: Android UI Patterns (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.groidify.uipatterns) for more nice UI Patterns.