# Swipe among activities in android

Tags: android, android-activity, swipe

i have 4 activities in which i have to swipe them right, left and if i am in last activity and swipe to the left then again first activity should be shown.

can anybody have any idea how i can achieve this? or some sample code?

thanks a lot.

Comment: I think it isn't a good idea since starting activity is a costly task so you can't make swiping be done smoothly.

Comment: u can do similar swiping using gallery....But i also think activity swiping is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve it by animaton..
But it will show as a Gallery view and you can swipe as well...
OnTouchEvent on every activity you can call another activity using intents by 
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.act_back_slide_enter, R.anim.act_back_slide_leave);

//overridePendingTransition("animation for activity which enters", "animation for activity which leaves");

I have not yet tried this... but we can make it in this form.. If you get success let me know.

Comment: yep i have implemented onGesterListner and onNewIntent() and i have set the launch mode of the activities to "single instance". so these activities has the single instance and on next and previous button i call the specific activity by sending intent and in my callee activity onNewIntent() method gets fired instead of onCreate. if you need my code i can send it to you aswell.

Answer (score 2):

@sajjoo Here goes your answer in **[deezapps widget](http://code.google.com/p/deezapps-widgets/)** with the questions below pointing at it

- [How to show multiple screens with right/left slide Gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544199/how-to-show-multiple-screens-with-right-left-slide-gesture)
- [How to create a slider screen (As in Tweetdeck) in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162157/how-to-create-a-slider-screen-as-in-tweetdeck-in-android)

and many more linked questions..

Comment: here in deezapps sample he is swiping views not activities. i need to swipe among activities.

Comment: @sajjoo then give try to [ActivityGroup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568468/activitygroup-example/4734984#4734984)

Answer (score 0):

I recently posted a question that covers a lot of this (my question is about using Swipe together with ScrollView, the Swipe gesture by itself works just fine):

[Swipe/Fling tab-changing in conjunction with ScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102993/swipe-fling-tab-changing-in-conjunction-with-scrollview)

If you read the sources I have listed and use the code I've provided then you should be able to do it.

Answer (score -1):

It's work fine... just must to delete the redundant R.java file...!

http://www.codeshogun.com/blog/2009/04/16/how-to-implement-swipe-action-in-android/