# Android WebView JQuery Mobile Horizontal Scroll

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, webview

I'm creating webview application in android using jquery mobile framework.
I need to show table that has width more than screen.
The horizontal scrollbar is not showing.
I have tried many ways but none worked for me.. (a lot of people facing the same problem with me, i have tried all of google search result link in page 1 to 3, some link from stackoverflow too)
Any suggestion?
*sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem, and I found a workaround (bug-fix?) for my situation via some experimentation.

In the JQuery Mobile CSS file ("jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.2.css" for me), I changed line 1119 from:

```
 .ui-content { border-width: 0; overflow: visible; overflow-x: hidden; padding: 15px; }
```

to:

```
 .ui-content { border-width: 0; overflow: visible; overflow-x: scroll; padding: 15px; }
```

This allowed my CSS (with absolute widths and coordinates) to be scrollable horizontally.

Once you modify your local copy of the JQuery Mobile CSS, don't forget to change the link in your html header.

Again, I'm not sure if the previous behavior was intentional or not. It may very well be inline with the design goals of the Jquery Mobile team. But this change worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Rather than monkey patching your jqm, I would suggest adding a <div> with the desired horizontal scroll with a CSS class. This might even be: `overflow-x: scroll !important;`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a bug that I found in this forum.
 http://forum.jquery.com/topic/horizontal-scroll-views

But here they talk about some other alternative for this called swipe by which you can achive this
 There are already some talk about this in site itself and you can refer it.

[Swipe among activities in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105380/swipe-among-activities-in-android)